# Assembly segmentation fault ( array )

Tags: arrays, gcc, assembly, x86

beginner in assembly here (IA-32 assembly). I keep getting a seg fault when compiling in gcc, I'm guessing its attempting to access forbidden memory, but I can't pin point it down. The task was to find the greatest common denominator of an array. I figured implementing this via an array with a side function gcd (returns the gcd of 2 numbers). Here is the code:

```
.intel_syntax noprefix 

.text

.global GCD

GCD:

push edi
push esi


mov edi, [ebp + 12] # number of elements in the array
mov esi, [ebp + 8] #array address 

mov eax, [esi] # place the first element of the array into eax
mov ecx, 1 # set the counter to 1

next_number: #accumulating the gcd of the entire array

cmp ecx, edi #if the counter reaches the max number of elements,
ja end       #end the the loop


push [esi + 4*ecx] #calling the gcd function, pushing the numbers on the 
push eax           #stack, so gcd can pick them up
call gcd 
add esp, 8


inc ecx            #increment the counter

jmp next_number    #next iteration


end:


  pop esi 
  pop edi 
  leave 
  ret
```

And the gcd side function:

```
# The C algorithm for finding the gcd of 2 numbers implemented in IA-32
#   while(y)
#   {
#     r = x % y;
#     x = y;
#     y = r;
#   }
#   return x;

.intel_syntax noprefix

.text


.global gcd

gcd:

enter 0,0

mov eax, [ebp + 8]
mov ecx, [ebp + 12]

loop:

cmp ecx, 0
je end

xor edx, edx
idiv ecx

mov eax, ecx
mov ecx, edx

jmp loop


end:

leave
ret
```

Comment: Surely, you don't get the fault while **compiling**? Learn to use a debugger. Also, comment your code, especially if you want others to help. That said, obviously you `push ebx` but never pop it. Also your `gcd` function zeroes `ecx`.

Comment: Will do. Compilation passes just fine, it's when I enter the values into the array, seg fault jump out. So it probably has something to do with the GCD.s code.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I mistyped `push ebx`, so according to you, I should push and pop `ecx`, so the gcd function doesn't zero it?

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't cause a fault by itself.

Comment: I apologize, it seems I forgot the initial `enter 0,0` at the beginning of the function. And yes, you were right, my `ecx` changes with gcd, I fixed it, thank you.

Comment: If you found and fixed your problem, please post an answer, and accept it using the check mark.  Otherwise people will continue to see this question as "unanswered".